# Triangular number sequence using Scala's Fibionacci

Tags: scala

The aim is to create a `Triangular number sequence` (1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21) using Scala's Fibionacci and the sixth digit need to be returned.

**Test**

```
test("triangular") {
  assert(Calculation.triangular(1, 3) === 21)
}
```

**Main**

```
def triangular(a: Int, b: Int) : Int = {
  lazy val s: Stream[Int] = a #:: s.scanLeft(b)(_+_)
  s(5)
}
```

**Outcome**

```
[info] - triangular *** FAILED ***
[info]   18 did not equal 21 (CalculationTest.scala:37)
[error] Failed: Total 9, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 8
[error] Failed tests:
[error]         testingscala.CalculationTest
[error] (test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed Jul 27, 2014 7:55:16 PM
```

`scanLeft` will work to create a Fibionacci sequence, but not to create a Triangular one.

Which option needs to be used to add 2, 3, 4, 5 and subsequently 6 to the last digit, which would result in a sequence of `1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like

```
val triangular: Stream[Int] = Stream.from(2).scanLeft(1)(_+_)
```

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have given an explanation of what that does. Stream.from creates an infinite stream of integers starting at 2, the scanLeft takes 1 as a starting number then adds the previous result to the next item in the infinite stream.